# postgres: two simple, equivalent queries but one is much slower

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running postgres (9.1) on ubuntu (12.04 LTS) on an amazon EC2 server.  I have this table:

```
    Table "public.principal_component"
    Column     |       Type       | Modifiers 
---------------+------------------+-----------
eigenvalue_id  | integer          | not null
stm_id         | integer          | not null
value          | double precision |

Indexes:
    "principal_component_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (eigenvalue_id, stm_id)
"pc_eigval_index" btree (eigenvalue_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "principal_component_eigenvalue_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (eigenvalue_id) REFERENCES
         eigenvalue(id)
    "principal_component_stm_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (stm_id) REFERENCES stm(id)
```

Edit:  this table contains 69,789,400 rows.

I tried to run this query:

```
select count(*) from principal_component where eigenvalue_id >= 801 and 
    eigenvalue_id <= 900
```

but it took a really long time so I cancelled.  So I used bash to run the query for each of the id values in the range in the above query:

```
time for ((a = 801; a <= 900; a++))
do 
    command="select count(*) from principal_component where eigenvalue_id=$a" 
    sudo -u postgres psql text_analytics -c "$command"`
done
```

and this bash command took 16s in total (for all 100 individual queries plus display etc.).

I then re-ran the first query, and timed it:  it took 250s.

Edit:  the result of the query is 0 - the count is 0 (as I expected)

Why the discrepancy?  Here are the explain plan results for each query:
Fast, individual query:

```
explain analyze select count(*) from principal_component where eigenvalue_id = 801"
                                     QUERY PLAN                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=168209.10..168209.11 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=13.367..13.369 
    rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using pc_eigval_index on principal_component  (cost=0.00..167883.16
       rows=130377 width=0) (actual time=13.344..13.344 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (eigenvalue_id = 801)
 Total runtime: 13.512 ms
(4 rows)
```

Slow "combined" query:

```
explain analyze select count(*) from principal_component where eigenvalue_id >= 801 and
    eigenvalue_id <= 900"
                                    QUERY PLAN                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=1618222.49..1618222.50 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=774.585..774.586
   rows=1 loops=1)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on principal_component  (cost=656742.39..1560409.48 rows=23125206
   width=0) (actual time=774.558..774.558 rows=0 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((eigenvalue_id >= 801) AND (eigenvalue_id <= 900))
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pc_eigval_index  (cost=0.00..650961.09 rows=23125206 
          width=0) (actual time=774.549..774.549 rows=0 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((eigenvalue_id >= 801) AND (eigenvalue_id <= 900))
Total runtime: 774.751 ms
(6 rows)
```

I know nothing about reading plans so I apologize in advance for missing something obvious.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: The fast query uses 13 ms to find out that there are no rows satisfying the condition `eigenvalue_id = 801` ergo := count=0. The slow one has to plow through 23M (index) tuples to get the count.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Answer (score 1):

Consider running `analyze` on your table, or `vacuum analyze` if it recently got massively updated, or increasing the amount of stats it's collecting if you had done that already. An estimate that is off by 23M rows is a bit too much.

Besides that, Postgres 9.1 isn't helping. 9.2 would do an index-only scan, eliminating the bitmap index scan in the process.

Aside: the queries aren't strictly equivalent or comparable. The first would need to be this instead:

```
select count(*) from ... group by igenvalue_id
```

Comment: thanks!  good point about the equivalency.  I would assume the group by would make the "slow" query even slower, but maybe that isn't the case?
Edit:  Thanks for the info about 9.2, I just used the default that I could install with apt-get, but it sounds like it is worth upgrading

When you say the estimate is off by 23M rows and you describe how to update / increase stats on the table, will that improve query speed or just improve the explain?  Thanks!

Comment: If the stats make Postgres correctly estimate a tiny number of rows, it won't use a bitmap index scan. Postgres resorts to that when it thinks a normal index scan will visit so many rows that it's faster to just gore through the hard drive. (In essence, a bitmap index scan is just a smarter version of a seq scan that doesn't read irrelevant chunks of hard drive.)

Comment: The fast query is so fast becaus it doesn't have to fetch any rows: `rows=130377 width=0) (actual time=13.344..13.344 rows=0 loops=1)`. The statistics are not very wrong. Your answer is excellent, but answers a different question.

Comment: @wildplasser: the stats are off by 23M rows in its estimates, though. That seems quite wrong to me, and answer the "Why the discrepancy?" question… At any rate, either OP didn't run `analyze`, or a `set statistics` statement seems in order to increase the sampling. With more accurate stats, he should get an index scan on 9.1, and an index-only scan on 9.2 — both would be faster than the bitmap index scan.

Comment: You are right about the stats being wrong, but the point is: we don't know the cardinality of `eigenvalue_id`. We _expect_ it to be rather low (10..100), but it could be >> 1000.